# Unreal engine - complaints for needing 8 GB of memory even though I have 8GB memory

Tags: macos, unreal-engine4

I have a Mac OS X with 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3 RAM and when I start unreal engine it complaints about Low RAM and asks that for best performance I should have at least 8 GB of RAM.

I'm not sure why is this is case, is it possible that its getting a lower share of RAM or something similar?

The Unreal Editor version is 4.7.5

Edit: The processor is 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7, and is 64 bit.

Edit: The graphic processor is Intel Iris Pro 1024 MB.

Comment: Is your OS 64 or 32 bit?

Comment: @TheBrain, its 64 bit. I added that information to the question. Let me know if I should add more information.

Comment: Sorry, did not see it. What type of graphics card to you use? Maybe the engine just gives you a general tip because it is running rather slowly on your machine?

Comment: Hey, I've updated the question. And this is what I'm worried about - is it possible that Unreal is only able to access a smaller portion of the memory than the memory available in my machine.

Comment: @DhruvKapur If you have an integrated GPU, some of your RAM is dedicated to it.  In most cases that shouldn't be a concern, but it does mean you have less than 8 GB for running applications.  According to Apple, the Iris Pro is dynamically allocated up to 1.5 GB of memory.

This page has more information about memory usage: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204349

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would UE4 not be able to access all of your RAM? I do not consider that case very likely.

Also, I would not worry about the RAM usage of UE4 too much. I do a lot of work with the engine and it rarely uses more than 3GB of RAM. Just make sure that your system as a whole has enough RAM for the running processes to prevent swapping.

Anyway, the bottleneck in your system is probably the graphics processor, so if your engine runs too slowly you should reduce the performance setting inside the engine.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to ensure that this is not happening.